# Separation of variables to integrate

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm having a difficult time finding the equation $y(t)$ knowing this equation: $y'(t)=ry(t)(1-y(t)).$

I know you have to separate the variables and integrate but for some reason it's not working for me.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does not work? The integration after separation ? Or the separation itself?

Comment: You might also need to use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt}&=ry(1-y)\\
\frac{dy}{y(1-y)}&=r\,dt\\
\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{dy}{y-1}&=r\,dt.
\end{align*}
You can finish from here.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{dy}{y(1-y)}=rdt$$ and integrate.
For your work:
The solution is given by $$y(t)=\frac{e^{r t}}{e^{c_1}+e^{r t}}$$